# Create react app proxy on when using direct normal links

Tags: reverse-proxy, create-react-app

Well in my application I have a link to download a report, the report is dynamically generated. During testing the generation happens in a test server, to which CRA normally correctly redirects for xhr requests.

The link is called like:

```
<a href={'/api/event/2/report/csv'} download={"report.csv"}>
    Load CSV report
</a>
```

CRA runs on port 3000, and it should act as a transparent host for all request to `/api` - redirecting them to `localhost:3000/api`. For the xhr requests this works smoothly by using the default reverse proxy. In package.json:

```
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:1337"
}
```

However this doesn't work at all. When I test above link I get a `failed no file` error on chrome. If I remove the `download` parameter I get a `404` page.

If I manually link to `http://localhost:1337/api/event/2/report/csv` it works (given there's no cookie so I the code shows a permission denied, but that's expected).

How can I get cra to work with this?

Comment: do you have any solution?